# If the Woocommerce default variant is out of stock, can another variant be set?

Tags: woocommerce, variant

If the Woocommerce Default Variant is out of stock, can another in-stock variant act as the default variant?
I always default the 1st variant on my website. If the 1st variant is out of stock and the customer has entered the product page, the selected variant appears with the phrase "out of stock" and this causes confusion.

Can you help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by modification of template "/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php" in my theme.
My code assumes that there is no more than one attribute per product.

First modification is in the 25 line, new code added here:

```
$selected=null;

foreach($available_variations as $prod_var){
    if($prod_var['is_in_stock'] || $prod_var['max_qty']>0) {
        $selected=current($prod_var['attributes']); // get the atttribute value
                                                  // from first available attribute
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, in the line 59 inside the foreach loop I modified function call and added optional param 'selected':

```
wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options(
        array(
                'options'   => $options,
                'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                'product'   => $product,
                'selected'=>($selected !== null) ? $selected : false,
            )
);
```

Tested on PHP 8.1 and Woocommerce 7.1.1